# Error in semantic exception return 0 rows in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I got the below error in hive while I am executing the hql like this.

Select a.col,b.col from tab a left join tab b on a.id =b.id and a.code in 
(Select c.code from tab c where c.id=123 and c.dec='123a');

Note: c.id is pk and c.dec is unique id

Error: semantic in exception 0 children returned.

Can any one help to resolve the above issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is happening because you are using a MySQL reserved keyword "desc" as your column name. So you can change it and try again.
You can refer to this link for the list of all the reserved keywords for MySQL :https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html